# iterating through an sql table efficiently

Tags: sql, loops, teradata

i have a table with 3 columns rcvr_id(user id),mth_id and tpv. mth_id is calculated as (2012-1900)*12+1,2,3(depending on if it is jan,feb,march). For example mth_id for Dec 2011 is 1344,Jan 2012 is 1345. the third column is tpv which is a decimal number and holds the transaction for the user for that month. An example table would be

```
rcvr_id           mth_id           tpv
                    .
                    .
                    .
1                 1326             23
1                 1327             13
1                 1329             9 
1                 1345             2
1                 1330             25
1                 1350             22
2                 1325             31
2                 1351             23    
3                 1327             130
3                 1329             90 
3                 1345             20
3                 1330             250
3                 1350             220  
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

and so on for other users(mth_ids may not be ordered)(rcvr_id and mth_id together make the primary key).Rcvr 2 has to be ignored because he does not have a tpv in between months 1326 and 1350.

A missing row value in mth_id indicates that for that month the rcvr had 0 tpv.
i.e,1328,1331 to 1344,1346 to 1350 tpv is 0.

Problem: I want to create a table which holds the two columns rcvr_id,mth_id and the third column -change_in_tpv. For example for the month 1327 .. the row would be like

```
1        1327       10,i.e (tpv of 1327-tpv of 1326)
```

**For user 1**:
*For month 1347, change in tpv=tpv of month 1347- tpv of month 1346(even though both rows are not existing, i have to take their tpvs as 0). For 1346, tpv would be = tpv of 1346-tpv of 1345=-2.*

For every receiver(that has a tpv between 1326 and 1350) i need to calculate the change in tpv for months 1327 to 1350.

Details : Teradata, more than million rows.How do i do it and do it with efficiency.

Multiple Queries/temp tables can be used

Comment: sry for so many edits :X

Comment: You've tagged this for Oracle but you say in the description that it is Teradata (and it is also tagged Teradata).  Where is Oracle involved in the process?

Comment: oh yeah sry my bad. out of habit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do most of this with a simple self-join:

```
select t.rcvr_id, t.mth_id, (t.tpv - coalesce(tprev.tpv, 0) as diff
from t left outer join
     t tprev
     on t.rcvr_id = tprev.rcvr_id and
        t.mth_id = tprev.mth_id+1
```

To get all the months requires having a driving table.  Let me assume that you have a tables of months, which I'll call months:

```
select tm.rcvr_id, tm.mth_id, (coalesce(t.tpv, 0) - coalesce(tprev.tpv, 0) as diff
from (select distinct t.rcvr_id, m.mth_id
      from t cross join
           months m
     ) tm left outer join
     t
     on tm.rcvr_id = t.rcvr_id and
        tm.mth_id = t.mth_id left outer join
     t tprev
     on t.rcvr_id = tprev.rcvr_id and
        t.mth_id = tprev.mth_id+1
```

If you don't have a month reference table, you can create the list of months on the fly (assuming each month is in the original table at least once):

```
select tm.rcvr_id, tm.mth_id, (coalesce(t.tpv, 0) - coalesce(tprev.tpv, 0) as diff
from (select r.rcvr_id, m.mth_id
      from (select distinct t.rcvr_id from t) r cross join
           (select distinct t.mth_id from t) m
     ) tm left outer join
     t
     on tm.rcvr_id = t.rcvr_id and
        tm.mth_id = t.mth_id left outer join
     t tprev
     on t.rcvr_id = tprev.rcvr_id and
        t.mth_id = tprev.mth_id+1
```

Comment: do u want me to create a month table m having just one column and values between 1326 and 1350? and do i have to use both the codes that you have written?

Comment: @ganducoder . . . Try the first version of the query.  It returns a row for every row in the original table.  It also sounded like you wanted to "pad" the output, by including months not in the table.  If so, you need a way get those months.  That is what the second query suggests.  I'm surprised, by the way, that if you have a column called mth_id, that you don't have a reference table for it.

Comment: reference table is not an issue , i can create that seperately. Supposing i make a table with one column mth_id with values from 1326 to 1350. Then i run both of your codes. Correct?